# How should I declare a class type list?

Tags: c#, list, class, variable-declaration

I have this example method, I am actually implementing it in another solution.

I want to declare a List that is going to take a different type depending on the value of the switch(), what should SOMETHING take?

```
class ReportStrings
{
    string date;
    string name;
}

class ReportIntegers
{
    int number;
    int amount;
}

public void main()
{
    List<SOMETHING> LReport;

    string reportname; //let's think it has a value

    switch (reportname)
    {
        case "ReportOne": LReport = new List<ReportStrings>; break;

        case "ReportTwo": LReport = new List<ReportIntegers>; break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(LReport.Count());    
}
```

Comment: Are there any similarities between the classes. how are you going to use this *mashinated* Frankenstein'd list, this question is pertinent to whether you should have an common interface, or just a list of `object`?

Comment: Typically you'd declare a common interface between the classes and have a list of the interface type, or you declare two different lists (probably in different scopes), since the objects in them will have different properties. Otherwise you could have a `List<object>` (if that's their nearest common base). It might be more helpful if you could say *why* you want to do this, becuase there's probably a better design.

Comment: @RufusL List of objects won't work because of covariance limitations

Comment: @DanielVygolov `var items = new List<object> {new ReportStrings(), new ReportIntegers()}; Console.WriteLine(items.Count);` works fine for me. Of course the downside is that you can't do anything useful with the contents without using reflection (or the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) operator) and casting (or [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)).

Comment: @DanielVygolov yes covariance is a limitation, but its not an issue depending on what the OP wants to do.

Comment: There's nothing about this sample code that means you couldn't use `List<object> LReport`, but your sample is trivial. To tell you what you really should do we'd need to see an example of what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some kind of a base class and inherit from it. Then create a List of the Base class and add your items like this:

```
class ReportBase { }
class ReportStrings:ReportBase
{
    string date;
    string name;
}

class ReportIntegers:ReportBase
{
    int number;
    int amount;
}

public void main()
{
    List<ReportBase> LReport;

    string reportname=null; //let's think it has a value

    LReport=GetList(reportname);

    Console.WriteLine(LReport.Count());    
}
private List<ReportBase> GetList(string reportname)
{
   var LReport = new List<ReportBase>(); 
   switch (reportname)
    {
        case "ReportOne": 

          LReport.Add(new ReportStrings(){ /* ...add your values here... */};
          break;
        case "ReportTwo": 
          LReport.Add(new ReportIntegers(){ /*...add your values here... */}; 
          break;
    }
    return LReport;
}
```

Comment: Note to future readers, always prefer composition over inheritance